# Not enough quota is available to process this command -WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I am working on a WPF application. I have implemented error handling and implemented   error mail sending feature for this application. So admin will get the error message if any error happened  in the application.
My issue is we are always getting a following error message.

> Error : **Not enough quota is available to process this command**
>
> MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.PostMessage(HandleRef hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam) at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.UpdateWindowSettings(Boolean enableRenderTarget, Nullable`1 channelSet) at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.UpdateWindowPos(IntPtr lParam) at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.HandleMessage(WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam) at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.HwndTargetFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled) at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled) at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o) at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs) at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)

We have used **MVVM light toolkit messengers, task** etc for this application.
Also I have a data grid in the application.

How we trace this error?  Anyone knows the reason of this “Not enough quota is available error”?
Any help would be appreciable.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: did you read
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584619/mysterious-not-enough-quota-is-available-to-process-this-command-in-winrt-port ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysterious "Not enough quota is available to process this command" in WinRT port of DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584619/mysterious-not-enough-quota-is-available-to-process-this-command-in-winrt-port)

Answer (score 4):

The reason and the action is here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms820778.aspx

Another link to help you out : http://blog.coultard.com/2012/01/fix-windows-error-0x80070718-not-enough.html

In short increasing the Page File size should be enough to get rid of the error
I had the same error a while ago and after increasing the Page File size it went away !

Answer (score 4):

Another potential source of the problem : https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/9247

> None. WPF is hooking the AppDomain exit logic. Unhandled exceptions from this call back 
>   result in process failure. There is no way for us to hook this call.
>
> I've actually brought this up to the CLR team because it's one of many
>   cases where we keep getting bitten by unhandled exceptions from
>   AppDomain exit.

In short : Process exit is called directly in the form (For example with Environnement.Exit) without cleaning up the DispatcherUnhandledException.