# C# - Error: Not enough quota is available to process this command

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I'm getting `Not enough quota is available to process this command. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070718)` error after reaching breakpoint at this part of code: `Stream localFolder = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.OpenStreamForReadAsync("articles.json");`. Is there something I'm doing wrong accessing my file?

I had read some articles about this error, but honestly I didn't catch up much of it. Could you please explain me simply what is it caused by?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# File.Copy Not enough quota](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415507/c-sharp-file-copy-not-enough-quota)

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you for that - I will inspect that. But still, why Visual Studio can't say where and why exactly the problem is?

Comment: Because it's not a VS error. It's an operating system error. It means you're running out of some resource, and the OS is telling you so. That resource could be disk space, handles, GDI resources, or something else.  How is VS supposed to guess where it might be? Fix your code that is leaking resources in all cases.